# How to use mysql as the data persistence backend in "Firebase + Validation Example" of vue.js?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, vue.js

I am learning `Laravel 5.2` and `vue.js`.

*The question is:* How to use `mysql` as the data persistence back end in **"Firebase + Validation Example"** of vue.js?
The original example uses Firebase as the data persistence backend.
http://vuejs.org/examples/firebase.html

Answer (score 0):

You should try something and post what you've tried to get the best answers on stack overflow.  The general concept is you need to re-write these two methods in the example:

```
methods: {
addUser: function () {
  if (this.isValid) {
    Users.push(this.newUser)
    this.newUser.name = ''
    this.newUser.email = ''
  }
},
removeUser: function (user) {
  new Firebase(baseURL + 'users/' + user.id).remove()
}
}
```

They should send requests to your laravel controller, and laravel handles adding and deleting in the database.